# Auto-advance in form fields

Tags: javascript, html, input, tabs

I have a simple script that auto-advances the cursor to the next field in my html form after one character is entered...and it works great for that. This is the simple code:

```
function autotab(current,to)
{
if (current.getAttribute && current.value.length==current.getAttribute("maxlength")) 
{   
        to.focus()          
    }
}
```

Then of course I use the onkeyup to advance it, like this:

```
<input onkeyup="autotab(this, document.jumble.w1b)" type="text">
```

Again, that works great. However, when I do Shift+Tab to go one box back, it auto-advances before I can type anything.

Does anyone have a code example of how to make Shift+Tab work? I have tried different variations of trying to use the keycodes to detect shift and tab, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prevent to.focus in case of `shift + tab` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veF2x/1/)

```
  function autotab(event, current,to)  {
       event = event || window.event;       
       if(event.keyCode < 65  ||  event.keyCode > 90){
         return ;
       }
       if (current.getAttribute && current.value.length==current.getAttribute("maxlength")) 
       {   
         to.focus()          
       }
    }
```

EDIT: Add event as first parameter in autotab: `<input onkeyup="autotab(event, this, document.jumble.w1b)" type="text">`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I paste your code...Firefox doesn't work at all and IE has the same (original) behavior. Any other ideas? This is the link: www.jasnachicago.org/fashion-jumble

Comment: Link: www.jasnachicago.org/fashion-jumble Type letters into the crossword puzzles. Thanks!

Comment: @Micah I edited my code . you need to pass event as parameter in autotab.

Comment: Thanks you. That breaks the script now, but I think I need to add something to the place where I implement (onKeyup="autotab(this, document.jumble.w1b)"). Do you know what I add there?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say what should I add as the "event" argument in the function call?

Comment: Pass event as : <input onkeyup="autotab(event, this, document.jumble.w1b)" type="text">. see the jsfiddle

Comment: OK, now we're back to the original problem. :( However, if I Shift+Tab and continue to hold down shift, it works, but of course as soon as I release the shift key, it tabs to the next box again.

Comment: I make the changes Now I am allowing alphabetic character only.