# After fill 4 number auto tab to next input field

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need a help to do this.

Below code I have used.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j42Jx/1/)

```
<div class="col-1 paddingright "><input type="number" id="num1"  maxlength="4" ></div>
<div class="col-1 paddingright"><input type="number"  id="num2"   maxlength="4" ></div>
<div class="col-1 paddingright"><input type="number"  id="num3"  maxlength="4"  ></div>
<div class="col-1"><input type="number" maxlength="4" id="num4"  ></div>
```

using

```
(function (){   
   $("#num1,#num2,#num3,#num4").on("keyup", function (e) {          
     var maxlength = 4;         
     var num1 = $("#num1").val().length;        
     var num2 = $("#num2").val().length;        
     var num3 = $("#num3").val().length;        
     var num4 = $("#num4").val().length;         
     $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));                
     if ( num1 &gt;= 4) {           
       $("#num2").focus();          
     }          
     if( num2 &gt;= 4){           
       $("#num3").focus();          
     }          
     if( num3 &gt;= 4){          
       $("#num4").focus();          
     }       
  });    
})();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-advance in form fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642774/auto-advance-in-form-fields)

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/j42Jx/1/)

Comment: @Prasanga simply adding query to the fiddle you shared seems to make your code work. Can you explain how does the accepted answer made it work better..?

Comment: Working better [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j42Jx/6/) but i need to know  this is working in phone and tab devices?

Comment: Please, please update your QUESTION like I did for you instead of adding comments

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
(function (){
$("#num1, #num2, #num3, #num4").on("keydown", function (t) {
    //add the key's you want to accept such as backspace or arrow keys etc.
    if (t.keyCode != 13 && t.keyCode != 8 && t.keyCode != 37 && t.keyCode != 38 && t.keyCode != 39 && t.button != 1 && t.button != 2 && t.button != 3) {
    var maxlength = 4;
    var num1 = $("#num1").val().length;
    var num2 = $("#num2").val().length;
    var num3 = $("#num3").val().length;
    var num4 = $("#num4").val().length;
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));

    if ( num1 >= 4) {
        $("#num2").focus();
        if( num2 >= 4){
            $("#num3").focus();
            if( num3 >= 4){
                $("#num4").focus();
                if (num4>=4){
                    $("#num4").val($("#num4").val().substr(0,3));
                }
            }

        }
    }     
    }

  });   
})();
```

Comment: Blocks user to enter more than 4 chars to inputs where html5 not available, allows user to press special keys like backspace, arrow keys etc.

Comment: This is working perfect, i have another one more question that is, this way working in devices like phone and tab ?

Comment: I didn't tested mobile applicability not sure if the keycodes match

Comment: Here i have another question that is i have filled all fields and if i need to change number in second or third field, changes can not be done, here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j42Jx/8/)

Comment: I have updated the answer. See the edited if section

Answer (score 1):

```
function tab(original, destination) {
if (original.getAttribute&&original.value.length==original.getAttribute("maxlength"))
destination.focus()
}


<input type="number" id="num1" maxlength="4" onKeyup"tab(this, document.yourform.num2)" />
<input type="number" id="num2" maxlength="4" onKeyup"tab(this, document.yourform.num3)" />
<input type="number" id="num3" maxlength="4" onKeyup"tab(this, document.yourform.num4)" />
<input type="number" id="num4" maxlength="4" />
```

Something along those lines.

Comment: i have updated and see last field, it can be entered more than 4 characters even i have given maxlength,[link](http://jsfiddle.net/j42Jx/3/)